# @Published variable doesn't reload my view after API call?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I believe that I have set up my view and view model correctly. I have also confirmed that the network request returns data (via the console). I am confused on why my published property isn't updating my view with the fetched data.

Here is my view model:

```
 class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<ProductViewModel, Never>()
    @Published var mensProducts = [StripeProduct]()
    
    init() {
    }
    
    func getMenItems() {
        // hit the URL and
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/bags") else {
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            // return the data asynchronously so that the call doesn't have to complete before loading the UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Decode data")
                self.mensProducts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([StripeProduct].self, from: data!)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
struct MenProducts: View {
    @ObservedObject var productVM = ProductViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(self.productVM.mensProducts) { item in
                        ProductView(productID: item.productID, photo: "menMerch", price: item.price, name: item.productName, height: geometry.size.height/2, width: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: self.productVM.getMenItems)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `StripeProduct` a `struct` or `class`? If it is a `class` can you test it by changing it to a `struct`?

Comment: It's a `struct`, I'm using it as a model for the data that I'm expecting back

Comment: It might be that the `ScrollView` needs an initial content to calculate its initial size, try assigning an initial value to `self.mensProducts` or add an invisible view like a `HStack` with a `Spacer()` in case `self.mensProducts` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I advise you to move your `getMenItems()` call to the `init()` method of `ProductViewModel`.

Then, you can remove the `.onAppear(perform: self.productVM.getMenItems)` in your `MenProducts` view and mark the method `private` in the `ProductViewModel` as no outside class/struct will be calling it.

I would also recommend you to not explicitly call the background queue with `DispatchQueue.main.async` as `URLSession` data task operations are asynchronous already.

You can read more about JSON decoding to Models in this great article: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/json-parsing-decoding/

Comment: This definitely worked. Thank you! I also didn't know that `URLSession` data task operations were already asynchronous, so thanks for that tip. I think I may have read some outdated guides

Comment: Just for educational purposes, do you know why my code didn't work in its previous state?